# Microsoft Graph Email API (webhooks) for personal accounts?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to get webhooks for an email account.
While this seems to work fine for enterprise accounts (Office365) using the `v1` endpoint, it seems I need to use the `beta` endpoint for personnal accounts (Hotmail, Live.com, Outlook.com etc.).

I'm not especially confident using something label as `beta` should I be worried? Is it reliable or is it going to break someday?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/beta` version of Microsoft Graph is a true "beta" and generally should not be used in a production environment. They can, and do, have breaking changes roll in without warning. They are intended for testing and future development, not for day-to-day use.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/versioning_and_support):

> Expect breaking changes to the beta version from time to time. Do not take a production dependency on /beta APIs.

also

> We make no guarantees that a beta feature will be promoted to the current version. When the Microsoft Graph API team believes that a beta feature is ready for general availability (GA), we will add that feature to the latest current version.

Comment: So no email subscriptions in production for MSA accounts?

Comment: At the moment, yes. You can take a dependency on it if you wish but I'd make sure you have some automated testing against it to buffer against changes/failures. I've seen a few places where developers have denoted this as a "Preview" in their own product so their users were aware there may be hiccups.

Comment: Do you know when we can except out of beta for MSA accounts?

Comment: I've not seen anything specific in terms of ETA. It looks like it was placed in beta last August so it isn't brand new. This isn't an indication that it will roll out soon but its a least worth noting that it wasn't rolled out last week.